# ReSharper 10.0.2 Unit Test Session Window Font Colors Dark (VS2013)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I am using ReSharper 10.0.2 in Visual Studio 2013.  In my unit test session window, the text in the window for failed tests is very dark for class names.  I have been unable to locate the setting to change this.  I don't recall it being like this in ReSharper 9.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These can be found in Fonts and Colours -> Resharper Stack Trace #

Where # is Method, Type, Path etc

Not the most straight forward thing to find!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio can sometimes get its knickers in a twist with the installed colours, and use the light theme colour settings in dark theme. You need to give it a poke to reset caches. The steps are available [in this support webpage](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546479-ReSharper-Fonts-Colors-settings-do-not-appear-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation).